# trying to see the bi bi-x while hover. what am i doing wrong?

Tags: html, css

I set the `bi bi-x` display to none; what i need to change/add in html/css?

```
<body>
<div class="col trying">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <i class="bi bi-x hide" style="position: absolute; margin-left: 130px;font-size: 22px; display:none;"></i>
          <h5 class="card-title" style="padding-top: 3px;">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text" style="width:150px;height:88px; overflow-y:auto;">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
          <br/>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

css-

```
   .card-body:hover + .hide{
    display: block;
  }
```

Comment: something went wrong. need to update the question

Comment: `+` is the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) and the `class="bi bi-x hide"` element isn't a sibling, it's a child/descendant.

Comment: how can I work this out?

Comment: See if replacing the `+` with either `>` (for children) or a space (for any descendant) fixes it. E.g. `.card-body:hover > .hide` or `.card-body:hover .hide`